# Como deslocar determinadas linhas para a esquerda na tabela em VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Possuo uma tabela que contem células com texto e valores que são colados diariamente em um modelo base. No entanto, ao colar novamente por cima da antiga tabela, algumas colunas saem com a formatação errada, pois onde deveria possuir valores numéricos aparece texto. Para isso, gostaria de fazer um botão para automatizar o processo de ajustar a tabela, recortando as linhas com valores numéricos e colando uma célula para a esquerda, com o intuito de ajustar a tabela.

No código abaixo eu fiz uma rotina para verificar em quais células do range possuem valores não numéricos e faça a seleção da linha até o final (para a direita), recorte e cole uma célula para a esquerda, no entanto estou tendo dificuldades neste último passo, pois ao colar os valores da linha, o excel está andando várias células para a esquerda, em vez de apenas uma. (Até Selection.Cut está funcionando corretamente)

```
    Sub Teste()

 For Each c In Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("C4:F10").Cells
 If IsNumeric(c.Value) = False Then c(1, 2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso, ao invés de colar nas colunas ao lado, poderia apenas atualizar a formatação da célula. Creio que simplificaria o código:

```
Sub Teste()
   For Each c In Worksheets("Planilha1").Range("C4:F10").Cells
   c.Select
   Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
   Next c
End Sub
```